# Set labels style in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

How can I change the style for all labels (and current/voltage as well) in circuitikz?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to [C, l_=$C_1$] ++(0,2) to [L, l_=$L_1$]
++(0,2) to [short,-*, i>=$I_1$] ++ (3,0) coordinate(l2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Here I want to make `C_1, L_1, I_1` larger. I tried with `\ctikzset{every label/.style={font=\Large}}` but with no effect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a section in the manual: https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.5.6

Basically, you have keys to change the 4 types of labels independently (they're not label in plain Ti*k*Z sense!):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipole label style/.style={font=\color{red}\Large}}
\ctikzset{bipole annotation style/.style={font=\color{blue}\ttfamily\Large}}
\ctikzset{bipole voltage style/.style={font=\Large}}
\ctikzset{bipole current style/.style={font=\color{green}\Large}}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to [C, l_=$C_1$, a^=ann] ++(0,2) to [L, l_=$L_1$, v^=$V_L$]
++(0,2) to [short,-*, i>=$I_1$] ++ (3,0) coordinate(l2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great! I saw this section but did not read it carefully. Thanks!